# SQL Between Dates- Format an Issue?

Tags: sql, date, format, ms-access-2007, between

I am trying to pull dates using the BETWEEN function, but was wondering if the format made a difference. The format that the dates are in now is 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I have seen a lot of examples that have the format in 'yyyy/mm/dd'. Can I pull the data using the format I have now, or do I need to convert the format? Thanks everyone.

Comment: What did you try? Did it work?

Comment: There are two things happening. The formatting of the dates is a localization setting for the database. The comparison is not related to how the data is shown, unless you are using text strings to compare to data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
Select EmailAddress,Birthday From table1 Where Birthday Between to_date('01-01-1946','MM-DD-YYYY') AND to_date('01-01-1988','MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: Select EmailAddress,Birthday                                    From table1                                                         Where Birthday Between '01-01-1988' AND '01-01-1946';

Comment: Tried pulling data using this format and still get nothing. Does the 'Date' column need to be a date format instead of text?

Comment: @realrx7 in the sample query you posted you need to swap those dates.  its BETWEEN earlier_dt AND later_dt.  You have it backwards.

Comment: I am using Access 2007 if that makes a diffrence....getting a syntax error now that reads...Syntax error (comma) in query expression

Comment: sometimes it can make a difference because different database systems can have different commands or syntax. Try putting a space after EmailAddress but before Birthday like this `EmailAddress, Birthday` that could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

the between clause should not have any formatting on the dates at all.

as in

```
BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
```